# Highlight a value on an axis

Tags: teechart

I would like to highlight a single value on an axis; similar to the way that stock charts display the live price on the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an annotation tool to show a textbox with the value and a color line tool if you also want to have vertical/horizontal line highlighting the value. However, both tools are only available with the Pro version, and these are two features that would be quite easy to achieve with custom drawing techniques at OnAfterDraw event.

Yeray Alonso

Steema Support Central